# Logstash date filter in a special case

Tags: logstash

I have the following format for my logs:

```
201407022000.log:2014-07-02 20:00;10.112.64.250;3;972819;ULC Primeline
```

Since it's a csv I could split the first parts pretty easily like this:

```
csv {
    columns => ["fulldate","ip","port","electricity","customer"]
    separator => ";"
    remove_field => "message" 
}
```

Now I want to split my *fulldate* field into a "whatever comes before the date" ( `201407022000.log:` ) and the actual date field ( `2014-07-02 20:00` )

I tried to use the date filter like this:

```
date {
    match => [ "fulldate", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm" ]
    timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

I receive the following **error**:

> Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"date",
>   :value=>"201407022000.log:2014-07-02 20:00",
>   :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "201407022000.log:2014-07-02 20:00" is malformed at
>   "000.log:2014-07-02 20:00", :level=>:warn}

Unfortunately this is not working logstash fails parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is failing is that you are trying to parse this:

```
201407022000.log:2014-07-02 20:00
```

With a filter that would match the format:

```
"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"
```

What you could do would be to use a grok on that field before parsing it:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "fulldate" => "[0-9.]+log:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}" }
  }
}
```

If you also want to capture the filename at the start, you could create a new pattern like (that would go in a file in your pattern directory, normally /opt/logstash/patterns in UNIX based systems) this:

```
LOGFILENAMEPATTERN [0-9.]+log
```

Then your grok would become:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "fulldate" => "%{LOGFILENAMEPATTERN:filename}:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}" ]
  }
}
```

Finally your date pattern would become:

```
date {
    match => [ "date", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" ]
    timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Note, that I have changed the name of the field you are matching against, as I renamed it in the grok, and I have replaced YYYY with yyyy, as Y is Year of Era, y is year, they are not the same (according to the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html))

Comment: You are soooo awesome :D I had to replace *"=>"* for *","* in the grok match but then everything worked! :))

Comment: Glad it helped :) I got the sytax for grok mixed up, corrected now, it should be either {} with => or [] with , IIRC [] with , is older notation

Comment: True, I tried your new variant also and it worked as well :) Thank you